# Finding a range date in sql , oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to find the date from one given date to today date . But my code doesent show anything.Any tipp?

```
select * from orders 
where order_date between to_date('2014-06-09','yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `to_date(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd')`, the `year` part would be `0015` instead of `2015`. Hence you don't get any results.

Use `trunc(sysdate)` instead.